MP4 video not playing on Safari iPhone
Sample video showing the problem: https://gget.it/io64/h264test13576.mp4 - can you play it on Safari?

I have a video on a HTML page
<video controls><source src="/files/test.mp4"></video>

that works on PC (Firefox, Chrome, etc.) but sadly it doesn't work on iPhone Safari (which I don't have handy, so difficult to debug): instead of the video there is a grey background.
What common reasons prevent a MP4 video to be played on Safari for iPhone?
Note: I've tried various things like:

controls => controls="true" as explained in HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad (not a duplicate)

adding playsinline

changing from <video ...><source src="..."></video> to <video ... src="...">


but the problem still exists.

Safari (also desktop) doesn't like the moov atom not being at the start of the file.
ffprobe -v trace -i h264test13576.mp4 2>&1 | grep -e 'mdat' -e 'moov'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x14a704930] type:'mdat' parent:'root' sz: 592695 56 597025
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x14a704930] type:'moov' parent:'root' sz: 4282 592751 597025
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x14a704930] type:'mvhd' parent:'moov' sz: 108 8 4274
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x14a704930] type:'trak' parent:'moov' sz: 1943 116 4274
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x14a704930] type:'trak' parent:'moov' sz: 2105 2059 4274
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x14a704930] type:'udta' parent:'moov' sz: 118 4164 4274

This fixes it:
ffmpeg -i h264test13576.mp4 -movflags faststart -c copy updated.mp4

ffprobe -v trace -i updated.mp4 2>&1 | grep -e 'mdat' -e 'moov'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x140605150] type:'moov' parent:'root' sz: 4022 40 596757
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x140605150] type:'mvhd' parent:'moov' sz: 108 8 4014
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x140605150] type:'trak' parent:'moov' sz: 2200 116 4014
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x140605150] type:'trak' parent:'moov' sz: 1609 2316 4014
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x140605150] type:'udta' parent:'moov' sz: 97 3925 4014
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x140605150] type:'mdat' parent:'root' sz: 592695 4070 596757


Wow, amazing find! Do you know why OBS (OBS Classic 0.659b, not the Studio version) did encode like this? More generally, is it common with older versions of ffmpeg (which OBS probably uses internally) to not have the moov atom at the beginning? Thanks!

They don't want to write the file twice to move it: https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/pull/1802

Nice find again @misterben! Why would it require a full rewrite of the file to put the moov atom at the beginning? What does this atom contain? Also, do you think this has changed in the latest versions of OBS?

@misterben What does updated.mp4 say about the colour space settings now? When I checked the original (via MediaInfo) it was saying that the colorspace is sYCC which is 10 or 12 bits (but H.264 uses 8-bit spaces like BT.709 or BT.601, etc). Basically the file had H264 data but its colour settings were specific to HEVC data somehow. I wonder if doing the FFmpeg remuxing also fixed it? (since FFmpeg does its own data analysis before putting settings in file).

@Basj The moov atom is the header chunk of the video, then the video/audio frames go into another chunk called mdat. The problem with MP4 design is that the header must list all frames, and their byte locations, and their byte lengths, and their timestamps, etc. This total info doesn't exist until recording has finished so the moov is made last and put at back. Players need to read it first. Now you understand that MP4 is not a streaming format (it is progressive downloaded). If OBS makes fragmented MP4 or M3U8 then use those options if you want to stream second by second.

@VC.One Thanks for this additional information! Isn't it possible when writing a MP4, to start the file with a placeholder for a moov atom with, say, 64 KB of null bytes (\x00) and then begin the actual video/audio frames at offset 64 KB? Then at the end of the video recording, the software can file seek at offset 0, write the actual moov data, padded with null bytes up to 64 KB, and then it's ok, without rewriting the entire file? (I don't know if 64 KB could work for multiple hours of videos?)

@Basj (1) Yes it's possible and sounds logical but no-one (camera manufacturer or software tool) does that. The nearest thing is the fragmented MP4 which by design has a small header (about 800 bytes) with basic info like width and height, then each following fragment has its own (now moof) header with duration for that fragment. fragments can be individual .m4s files which act like .ts files or can be joined into being one bigger file (still called .mp4) (2) From a quick check I see OBS does do fragmented MP4 recording. It might help with getting iOS playback from output (no edits).

@VC.One Good to know! Since when do you think OBS has switched from non-fragmented MP4 to now fragmented MP4?

@Basj In OBS Settings, go to Output and choose the Recording tab. Does it look similar to this image? Where the  Recording Format: is set to Fragmented MP4?... The feature was mentioned in the OBS blog/article

@VC.One Thanks! I think posting a link to https://obsproject.com/blog/obs-studio-hybrid-mp4 with a brief summary Fragmented vs non Fragmented would be a valuable answer on its own! Especially with this image in the answer: https://obsproject.com/media/pages/blog/obs-studio-hybrid-mp4/4e708fd0e3-1721156355/blog_mp4_transparent_fixed.png Would you want to post it? (I'll vote of course)

Additional information:  the answer mp4 H264 video won't play in iPhone safari gives a hint about the reasons why Safari won't play this video:

Some software (many versions of OBS, for example) chooses to put the movie box metadata last.


Apple’s implementation of the player on iOS apparently requires the movie box metadata to be at the front of the file, after the header


